# Duplicate URL's (Double URL) in Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.8

I'm using joomla platform. I have small issue with a url.

**karisalmedia.com** is my domain and **online** is the subfolder. in my site article comment shared on community page.

if i access the url from the community page it's going to 404 page.

- Correct url: `https://karisalmedia.com/online/index.php/ta/236-2018-07-02-05-23-16`
- Wrong url: `https://karisalmedia.com/online/online/index.php/ta/236-2018-07-02-05-23-16`

How to remove one **/online**?

Comment: Please show the code/data that you suspect is to blame for this issue.  Your site is down for construction, so we can't understand the issue by visiting.  Your `Watts new feature!` link @ https://karisalmedia.com/online/index.php/ta/236-2018-07-02-05-23-16 is offering a single-online link, so it is hard to help you.

Comment: Additionally, once you can write up a complete, verifiable, clear question, I will ask you to post your Joomla-specific question on Joomla Stack Exchange.  This is the community that Joomla developers wish for you to interact with.   In your **Administrator** -> **Help** tab, the 2nd last item says **Stack Exchange**. 
  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/  (While you are over there, take a moment to earn your Informed badge.)